# How to retrieve cart data as json in woocommerce

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to build a cart inside angular. What I want is to retrieve the cart items from woocommerce as json so I can use it in the angular framework. I have search the woocommerce api documentation but couldn't find anything about cart data.

Comment: What have you tried to get the JSON so far? Please show in your question the code you've written. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: I didn't had any code where I can work from until Shawn posted something that I missed. Right now I am trying to get the http authentication to work for woocommerce rest api. I have posted the issue here right now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833326

Answer (score 1):

As per their documentation at the following address:

http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/

I believe the part you will want will be under "Orders". The list of properties are there.

Comment: Thanks I missed that one. I am trying to get the http authentication to work now. But getting an error can you see what I am doing wrong here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833326

Comment: I will comment directly on that question.