# Getting Invalid Signature error with woocommerce rest api using oauth 1.0a

Tags: oauth, woocommerce

I am getting an invalid signature error in woocommerce rest api. I am also using the oauth 1.0a script from ddo https://github.com/ddo/oauth-1.0a. I generated the api keys twice. Also removed the version parameter inside de oauth script like requested on the woocommerce rest api documentation http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/

url

```
test.dev/wc-api/v3/orders/line_items?oauth_consumer_key=ck_858f9cf8cda8085d5677b2b1d4c12d10897e9702&oauth_nonce=MyriSapnWSopIusSjjuqJ8PLi6RWr0L9&oauth_signature=VfgINTX1FWYu551%2FxlLfipFnDQ8%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1443481966
```

error

```
{"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"Invalid Signature - provided signature does not match"}]}
```

js

```
var oauth = OAuth({
    consumer: {
        public: 'ck_858f9cf8cda8085d5677b2b1d4c12d10897e9702',
        secret: 'cs_7f429ec99905bb444e290bd4852a0c0da2545b21 '
    },
    signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1'
});

var request_data = {
    url: 'http://test.dev/wc-api/v3/orders/line_items',
    method: 'GET',
}

$http({
    url: request_data.url,
    method: request_data.get,
    params: oauth.authorize(request_data)
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
});;
```

Comment: You should not show your real keys for security! You may want to regenerate those now.

Is it the space at the end of the secret key?

Comment: I am too tired, I am overlooking everything (facepalm). I am retrieving json data now. However in the console log it still shows 401 unauthorized. But when I click on the link it then shows a page with all the data in it.
console.log: 
Object {data: Object, status: 401, config: Object, statusText: "Unauthorized"}

Comment: Not sure if you are using PHP to access the API, in case you are then the following library will help : [REST API Library](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library)

Comment: I am using Javascript. I got it to work "somewhat" but only when I open the url in the browser. When for example javascript console logs the rest api url data it shows 401 unautherized error but not when I go there via the browser.

Comment: Hi. Did you get it to work? Can you please share the working js snippet?

Comment: @Samarth Agarwal I fixed it with the code below. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using a service from Abdul Ahmad: httpService.js

```
angular.module('httpService', []).factory('httpService', httpService);
httpService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

function httpService($http, $q) {

    var methods = {
        httpGet : 'GET',
        httpPost : 'POST',
        httpPut : 'PUT',
        httpDelete : 'DELETE'
    };

    function baseGet(url) {
        return $http.get(url).then(
                function (result) {
                    return result.data;
                },
                function (result) {
                    return $q.reject(result);
                }
            );
    }
    function httpWithParams(url, method, params, data) {
        return $http({
                url: url,
                method: method,
                params: params,
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            }).then(
                function (result) {
                    return result.data;
                },
                function (result) {
                    return $q.reject(result);
                }
            );
    }
    function handleError(error) {
            console.log(error);
    }

    return {
        baseGet: baseGet,
        httpWithParams: httpWithParams,
        handleError: handleError,
        methods: methods
    }
}
```

And then used this:

```
var oauth = OAuth({
    consumer: {
        public: 'ck_000',
        secret: 'cs_000'
    },
    signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1'
});

function getMyData() {

    var request_data = {
        url: 'http://test.dev/wc-api/v3/products',
        method: 'get',
    }

    return  returnData = httpService.httpWithParams(request_data.url, request_data.method, oauth.authorize(request_data))
    .then(function(data) {
        return data;
    }, function(data) {
        httpService.handleError(data);
        return data;
    });
}
```

Made some modification in the oauth file:

```
if (typeof(module) !== 'undefined' && typeof(exports) !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = OAuth;
    var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
}

/**
 * Constructor
 * @param {Object} opts consumer key and secret
 */
function OAuth(opts) {
    if(!(this instanceof OAuth)) {
        return new OAuth(opts);
    }

    if(!opts) {
        opts = {};
    }

    if(!opts.consumer) {
        throw new Error('consumer option is required');
    }

    this.consumer            = opts.consumer;
    this.signature_method    = opts.signature_method || 'HMAC-SHA1';
    this.nonce_length        = opts.nonce_length || 32;
    //this.version             = opts.version || '1.0';
    this.parameter_seperator = opts.parameter_seperator || ', ';

    if(typeof opts.last_ampersand === 'undefined') {
        this.last_ampersand = true;
    } else {
        this.last_ampersand = opts.last_ampersand;
    }

    switch (this.signature_method) {
        case 'HMAC-SHA1':
            this.hash = function(base_string, key) {
                return CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(base_string, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
            };
            break;

        case 'HMAC-SHA256':
            this.hash = function(base_string, key) {
                return CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(base_string, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
            };
            break;

        case 'PLAINTEXT':
            this.hash = function(base_string, key) {
                return key;
            };
            break;

        case 'RSA-SHA1':
            throw new Error('oauth-1.0a does not support this signature method right now. Coming Soon...');
        default:
            throw new Error('The OAuth 1.0a protocol defines three signature methods: HMAC-SHA1, RSA-SHA1, and PLAINTEXT only');
    }
}

/**
 * OAuth request authorize
 * @param  {Object} request data
 * {
 *     method,
 *     url,
 *     data
 * }
 * @param  {Object} public and secret token
 * @return {Object} OAuth Authorized data
 */
OAuth.prototype.authorize = function(request, token) {
    var oauth_data = {
        oauth_consumer_key: this.consumer.public,
        oauth_timestamp: this.getTimeStamp(),
        oauth_nonce: this.getNonce(),
        oauth_signature_method: this.signature_method
        //oauth_version: this.version
    };

    if(!token) {
        token = {};
    }

    if(token.public) {
        oauth_data.oauth_token = token.public;
    }

    if(!request.data) {
        request.data = {};
    }

    oauth_data.oauth_signature = this.getSignature(request, token.secret, oauth_data);

    return oauth_data;
};

/**
 * Create a OAuth Signature
 * @param  {Object} request data
 * @param  {Object} token_secret public and secret token
 * @param  {Object} oauth_data   OAuth data
 * @return {String} Signature
 */
OAuth.prototype.getSignature = function(request, token_secret, oauth_data) {
    return this.hash(this.getBaseString(request, oauth_data), this.getSigningKey(token_secret));
};

/**
 * Base String = Method + Base Url + ParameterString
 * @param  {Object} request data
 * @param  {Object} OAuth data
 * @return {String} Base String
 */
OAuth.prototype.getBaseString = function(request, oauth_data) {
    return request.method.toUpperCase() + '&' + this.percentEncode(this.getBaseUrl(request.url)) + '&' + this.percentEncode(this.getParameterString(request, oauth_data));
};

/**
 * Get data from url
 * -> merge with oauth data
 * -> percent encode key & value
 * -> sort
 *
 * @param  {Object} request data
 * @param  {Object} OAuth data
 * @return {Object} Parameter string data
 */
OAuth.prototype.getParameterString = function(request, oauth_data) {
    var base_string_data = this.sortObject(this.percentEncodeData(this.mergeObject(oauth_data, this.mergeObject(request.data, this.deParamUrl(request.url)))));

    var data_str = '';

    //base_string_data to string
    for(var key in base_string_data) {
        data_str += key + '=' + base_string_data[key] + '&';
    }

    //remove the last character
    data_str = data_str.substr(0, data_str.length - 1);
    return data_str;
};

/**
 * Create a Signing Key
 * @param  {String} token_secret Secret Token
 * @return {String} Signing Key
 */
OAuth.prototype.getSigningKey = function(token_secret) {
    token_secret = token_secret || '';

    if(!this.last_ampersand && !token_secret) {
        return this.percentEncode(this.consumer.secret);
    }

    return this.percentEncode(this.consumer.secret) + '&' + this.percentEncode(token_secret);
};

/**
 * Get base url
 * @param  {String} url
 * @return {String}
 */
OAuth.prototype.getBaseUrl = function(url) {
    return url.split('?')[0];
};

/**
 * Get data from String
 * @param  {String} string
 * @return {Object}
 */
OAuth.prototype.deParam = function(string) {
    var arr = string.split('&');
    var data = {};

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var item = arr[i].split('=');
        data[item[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item[1]);
    }
    return data;
};

/**
 * Get data from url
 * @param  {String} url
 * @return {Object}
 */
OAuth.prototype.deParamUrl = function(url) {
    var tmp = url.split('?');

    if (tmp.length === 1)
        return {};

    return this.deParam(tmp[1]);
};

/**
 * Percent Encode
 * @param  {String} str
 * @return {String} percent encoded string
 */
OAuth.prototype.percentEncode = function(str) {
    return encodeURIComponent(str)
        .replace(/\!/g, "%21")
        .replace(/\*/g, "%2A")
        .replace(/\'/g, "%27")
        .replace(/\(/g, "%28")
        .replace(/\)/g, "%29");
};

/**
 * Percent Encode Object
 * @param  {Object} data
 * @return {Object} percent encoded data
 */
OAuth.prototype.percentEncodeData = function(data) {
    var result = {};

    for(var key in data) {
        result[this.percentEncode(key)] = this.percentEncode(data[key]);
    }

    return result;
};

/**
 * Get OAuth data as Header
 * @param  {Object} oauth_data
 * @return {String} Header data key - value
 */
OAuth.prototype.toHeader = function(oauth_data) {
    oauth_data = this.sortObject(oauth_data);

    var header_value = 'OAuth ';

    for(var key in oauth_data) {
        if (key.indexOf('oauth_') === -1)
            continue;
        header_value += this.percentEncode(key) + '="' + this.percentEncode(oauth_data[key]) + '"' + this.parameter_seperator;
    }

    return {
        Authorization: header_value.substr(0, header_value.length - this.parameter_seperator.length) //cut the last chars
    };
};

/**
 * Create a random word characters string with input length
 * @return {String} a random word characters string
 */
OAuth.prototype.getNonce = function() {
    var word_characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
    var result = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < this.nonce_length; i++) {
        result += word_characters[parseInt(Math.random() * word_characters.length, 10)];
    }

    return result;
};

/**
 * Get Current Unix TimeStamp
 * @return {Int} current unix timestamp
 */
OAuth.prototype.getTimeStamp = function() {
    return parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000, 10);
};

////////////////////// HELPER FUNCTIONS //////////////////////

/**
 * Merge object
 * @param  {Object} obj1
 * @param  {Object} obj2
 * @return {Object}
 */
OAuth.prototype.mergeObject = function(obj1, obj2) {
    var merged_obj = obj1;
    for(var key in obj2) {
        merged_obj[key] = obj2[key];
    }
    return merged_obj;
};

/**
 * Sort object by key
 * @param  {Object} data
 * @return {Object} sorted object
 */
OAuth.prototype.sortObject = function(data) {
    var keys = Object.keys(data);
    var result = {};

    keys.sort();

    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var key = keys[i];
        result[key] = data[key];
    }

    return result;
};
```

Comment: The method httpWithParams takes 4 parameters but you have passed only 3. How is it going to work?

Comment: this is for getting if you need to post then use post method and add data parameter at the end

Comment: Hi. I really appreciate you posting the working code. But I am not able to POST using this code. I keep getting the following errors.

`OPTIONS http://samarth.cloudapp.net/wc-api/v3/products?oauth_consumer_key=ck_eb425c…th_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1455021731&oauth_version=1.0

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://samarth.cloudapp.net/wc-api/v3/...SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1455021731&oauth_version=1.0. 
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401`

Comment: It will be really helpful if you could help me make a POST to the woocommerce API.

Comment: Are you using the oauth from my first post?

Comment: I also modified the oauth code if I remember correctly. Can you try the oauth code that I just added?

Comment: Hi.`I am using the library https://github.com/ddo/oauth-1.0a. I will add your code and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that your $http method is getting the value of `request_data.get` instead of `request_data.method`. I'm sure that's what you were overlooking lol